# how to retrieve data from webserver in arduino and ethernet shield

Tags: arduino

Excuse me I want to ask. The case like this I have a link on my webserver https://sistemkontrolsmartroom.000webhostapp.com/on-admin/result.txt inside this link contains data in the form of numbers that can be changed according to the data yng in inputkan.
What function is in use so that arduino can read the data contained in the link. For example if arduino read data 2 then the lights on. and if arduino read data 1 then the lights off
Thanks.

Comment: there is bit confusion in your question, so please answer my question. When you run a link from your arduino, it will return a number 1 or 2, if it is 2 lights on and if 1 then lights off. Isn't it what you need?

Comment: Please try to post some codes.

Comment: please respond to every reply you receive. Accept and upvote answers if you think it should help others with similar doubt.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `AT+HTTPREAD` to read the http server response. It would read the response from the server, here it would be either 1 or 2. This [link](http://m2msupport.net/m2msupport/athttpread-get-response-from-http-server/) would be helpful. Store the response to a variable. The response (now in variable) would be in bytes, use `atoi()` function to convert it to integer for your comparison.

P.B : As you haven't added any codes, if you haven't started anything (coding) this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cpgQOmQwUL8) would be helpful. You can download sketches provided by him in his videos they are useful.